# Any way to undisable (not Unlock) my phone without factory resetting / restoring it?

Tags: iphone

I've never connected my iPhone to iTunes before. I don't have anything backed up on this phone, and the stuff on this phone is very important.

This phone somehow randomly kept trying to unlock itself while it was in my pocket (I guess buttons kept getting pressed). I looked at the phone and it says "iPhone is disabled. connect to iTunes". Apparently it does this if it tried unlocking with an incorrect passcode 10 times. Great...

So now this phone is disabled. It has my fingerprint unlock. I know the passcode. It's just disabled. And I don't have anything backed up on any iTunes. I have the iPhones serial number as well. Can I get this thing undisbaled for a second?

Comment: Normally, it allows access after some time(could be hours).

Comment: If you have important data, why do you not also have a backup?

Comment: @PratikaRana Now that I think about it, it might have took more than 10 tries. I remember vaguely seeing the 15 minute timeout, and then an hour timeout followed by maybe another hour timeout. I kinda just ignored these. Currently it doesn't mention a timeout time (just says "iPhone disabled. connect to iTunes"). It's been 12+ hours so far (left it on over night). Hopefully you're right and it undisables within another day.

Comment: Check www.icloud.com and see if the settings shows a backup in the iCloud for you. iCloud backups can recover your information. (You can also check via another Apple device if you have another.